# using jQuery with Asana

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jsonp, asana

I want to use Asana like this, but I always receive the message about invalid label.

```
$.ajax
  url: "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects"
  username: apikey
  dataType: "jsonp"
  success: (projects) ->
```

**Update:**

Okay, it looks like something changed. The JSONP call seemed to work fine. See also the thread below. This is what this CoffeeScript is based upon. Also other stuff things I worked on stopped working. Did something about the Asana-API change? There are no updates regarding this.

[retrieve RESTful data using JQuery ajax() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280001/retrieve-restful-data-using-jquery-ajax-method)

Comment: this is not a proper jquery ajax format

Comment: rahul take a look at tags for this question

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana)

We have not changed anything in the API that we believe would affect this request. I don't actually see how it could have ever worked, since the Asana API does not currently support the "jsonp" return type (we plan to as soon as we can offer it securely, when it is coupled with OAuth). The JSONP protocol has specific requirements of the server (outputting a javascript function call) in order for it to work -- and we have not implemented those requirements.

Comment: Hmm, maybe was related to the fact one can have some basic access when logged in, even from third party sites, which also is a security risk.